# how to find frequent item in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the most frequent value of item in an array of object in transportation item

I could not find because it's object I guess

```
[{
    author: {
        id: 5 d3b0e91a75d210329589789,
        username: 'humam1'
    },
    _id: 5 d43bf7cc9f4671049d17821,
    text: '',
    rate: null,
    safety: 25,
    family: 50,
    population: 50,
    traffic: 50,
    hospitals: 50,
    transportation: 'taxi',
    creditCard: '100',
    medicalTourism: null,
    internet: null,
    fun: null,
    education: null,
    dailyAverageExpense: null,
    dailyAverageHotel: null,
    tipping: null,
    nightLife: null,
    createdAt: 2019 - 08 - 02 T04: 43: 40.669 Z,
    __v: 0
}, {
    author: {
        id: 5 d3ff8a25d847a02758dcc99,
        username: 'hussain'
    },
    _id: 5 d43c3867401e9121cafd805,
    text: '',
    rate: null,
    safety: null,
    family: null,
    population: 75,
    traffic: null,
    hospitals: 50,
    transportation: 'taxi',
    creditCard: '',
    medicalTourism: null,
    internet: null,
    fun: null,
    education: null,
    dailyAverageExpense: null,
    dailyAverageHotel: null,
    tipping: null,
    nightLife: null,
    createdAt: 2019 - 08 - 02 T05: 00: 54.127 Z,
    __v: 0
}, {
    author: {
        id: 5 d4476d08379b60aa57bdcf6,
        username: 'test1'
    },
    _id: 5 d4477738379b60aa57bdcf7,
    text: '',
    rate: null,
    safety: null,
    family: null,
    population: null,
    traffic: null,
    hospitals: null,
    transportation: 'airplane',
    creditCard: '',
    medicalTourism: null,
    internet: null,
    fun: null,
    education: null,
    dailyAverageExpense: null,
    dailyAverageHotel: null,
    tipping: null,
    nightLife: null,
    createdAt: 2019 - 08 - 02 T17: 48: 35.755 Z,
    __v: 0
}]
```

The result should be `taxi`

Comment: What have you tried until now and what problems are you facing?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service where you just show some data and tell us what you want done to it. It is expected that you show your own attempts to solve your issue and others help you modify *your code* when it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the count of occurrence of same `transportation` using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Again we can use another iteration (I used `reduce()`) to get the max count occurrence.

```js
const data = [{transportation: 'taxi'}, {transportation: 'taxi'},{transportation: 'airplane'}]
const count = data.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur.transportation] = acc[cur.transportation] ? acc[cur.transportation] + 1 : 1, acc), {})
const result = Object.keys(count).reduce((acc, cur) => count[acc] > count[cur] ? acc: cur)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a mapping of the counts of each transportation `value` from the original object (I have minified it below after making it into a valid JSON object) then use reduce on this `map` to get the most frequent key:

```js
const json = [{"author":{"id":"5d3b0e91a75d210329589789","username":"humam1"},"_id":"5d43bf7cc9f4671049d17821","text":"","rate":null,"safety":25,"family":50,"population":50,"traffic":50,"hospitals":50,"transportation":"taxi","creditCard":"100","medicalTourism":null,"internet":null,"fun":null,"education":null,"dailyAverageExpense":null,"dailyAverageHotel":null,"tipping":null,"nightLife":null,"createdAt":"2019-08-02T04:43:40.669Z","__v":0},{"author":{"id":"5d3ff8a25d847a02758dcc99","username":"hussain"},"_id":"5d43c3867401e9121cafd805","text":"","rate":null,"safety":null,"family":null,"population":75,"traffic":null,"hospitals":50,"transportation":"taxi","creditCard":"","medicalTourism":null,"internet":null,"fun":null,"education":null,"dailyAverageExpense":null,"dailyAverageHotel":null,"tipping":null,"nightLife":null,"createdAt":"2019-08-02T05:00:54.127Z","__v":0},{"author":{"id":"5d4476d08379b60aa57bdcf6","username":"test1"},"_id":"5d4477738379b60aa57bdcf7","text":"","rate":null,"safety":null,"family":null,"population":null,"traffic":null,"hospitals":null,"transportation":"airplane","creditCard":"","medicalTourism":null,"internet":null,"fun":null,"education":null,"dailyAverageExpense":null,"dailyAverageHotel":null,"tipping":null,"nightLife":null,"createdAt":"2019-08-02T17:48:35.755Z","__v":0}]
    
const counter = (arr) => {
  var count = {}
  arr.forEach(val => count[val] = (count[val] || 0) + 1)
  return count
}

const transportationCounts = counter(json.map(obj => obj.transportation))
const mostFrequentTransportation = Object.keys(transportationCounts).reduce((a, b) => transportationCounts[a] > transportationCounts[b] ? a : b);
console.log(mostFrequentTransportation)
```